# OOP problem related to default constructor having setter from cin and pointer to object doesn't return the name

Tags: c++, oop

I have 3 fields,one void method to return minimum price,constructor with 3 parameters and a getter for name.
a) First I need to create an instance for this constructor and to return the name and the minimum price which I did.
b) Secondly I need to create a default constructor(so no parameters) and a setter method to set the fields but from the keyboard.
c) In the end I need to do the same thing as at a) but by using a pointer.

My problem is:
I don't know how to make b) cuz the setter doesn't work and when I try to return the name of the pointer object from c) it doesn't show anyting

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CTest{

    private:
    string name;
    float price1;
    float price2;

public:
    CTest(string name,float price1,float price2){
        this->name = name;
        this->price1 = price1;
        this->price2 = price2;
    }

    CTest(){};

    void set_values(string name,float price1,float price2){
        cin>>name;
        cin>>price1;
        cin>>price2;

    }

   string get_name(){
       return name;
    }

    void minimum_price() {
        if(this->price1 < this->price2)
            cout<<"Min price is " <<this->price1;
        else
            cout<<"Min price is " <<this->price2;
    }


};

int main(){

    CTest P ("Phone",450.9f,500.9f);
    cout<<P.get_name();
    cout<<endl;
    P.minimum_price();



CTest *A = new CTest("Something",4.5f,3.5f);
cout<<A->get_name();
cout<<endl;
A->minimum_price();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is wrong

```
void set_values(string name,float price1,float price2){
    cin>>name;
    cin>>price1;
    cin>>price2;
}
```

because the three parameters hide the names of the your class member variables. So the values from `cin` go to the parameters not to your class.

What you probably meant is this

```
void set_values(){
    cin>>name;
    cin>>price1;
    cin>>price2;
}
```

Now the values from `cin` will go to your class.

Comment: Also he could write `cin>>this->name` but it would be meaningless to have same names in parameters